# Mono does not like Euro symbole?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have in public class variable this:

```
     string[]  par_semb =  new string[3] {"$","€","Tl"};
```

When I use my program in mono $ and Tl are displayed but not € sign.
But when I change my string array as below

```
     string[]  par_semb =  new string[3] {"$","EURO","Tl"};
```

The "EURO" is displayed.

Working on windows there is no problem. This occurs when I run it on mono.

Any idea ?

PS I'm using c# 8 express edition and working with win forms. It's the same program running on win7 and on wine.

[image]
[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Sure the output font your using contains that glyph?

Comment: And how are you compiling the code? Have you tried using `\u20AC` instead? Where are you displaying the result?

Comment: Perhaps your mono development environment is not set to use UTF-8 for editing and your windows system is

Comment: Or perhaps your Mono is configured to use iso8859-1 encoding while your Windows is using windows-1252. iso8859-1 doesn't include the € symbol.

Comment: @JonSkeet I display on label and viewitem (differently both of them are not displayed). I compile with the builder of the editor. I am affraid I am beware of the rules to compile but I will look for.

Comment: @xanathos when I type in gedit alt gr+e I get € sign.

Comment: What sort of label is this? We have no idea what kind of application you're writing. Again, try using `"\u20AC"` as an alternative way of writing the string literal so that at least we know that isn't the issue.

Comment: @infixed I checked my ubuntu with locale -a everything is ok.It's tr_TR.UTF8 which include € sign.  As I told I can type with alt gr + e € sign.

Comment: I added with what I'm working sorry!.

Comment: Well, an agnostic solution would be to use the escape sequence that @Jon Skeet mentioned.   You could see if the euro symbol actually gets into the source code file by looking at it with some text tool.  For example, `less`.  I can see some compilers not wanting to deal with UTF-8 in string constants

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "C# 8 express edition" - there's no such thing as C# 8. But we *still* don't know what happens when you try using the escape sequence...

Comment: @Jon Skeet I tried \u20AC € is visible on text of combo box but not in dropped part, neither on label.nor list view. However textboxes shows the euro sign either with escape sequence or with the symbole.

Comment: Sounds like it may be a Mono Winforms implementation issue then.